# Unit of work, rollback options

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unit-of-work

I'm trying to build a system which follows the repository and unit of work patterns to allow persistence ignorance/unit testing, etc etc. I'm looking for advice on dealing with Rollback. Ideally I want to use POCO's but I think I might need to at least implement an interface to provide a few bits and pieces.

So lets say we have two repositories, one context/unit of work.

I add one item, amend another item and delete a third item. Repeat for second repository, then I call rollback.

In the past I've used something akin to a DataSet for this. Each object has a state of pendingNew, pendingAmended, pendingDeleted, clean. There is also a copy last persisted version of the object for rollback.

How would you implement this?

EDIT:

Ok, here's what I think I'm actually trying to get my head around. Prepare to be patterned :)

Ultimately the project is WPF MVVM. So we're looking at the Model to what ever the store is here.

I think I've been trying to conflate the model with the idea of repository, where as I think the model should use the UOW and Repositories to provide the features the model needs to provide. Does that sound better?

I want complete persistence ignorance, so imagine my domain includes a Customer, an Order and OrderLines.

The GUI let's say has one button new order which allows the user to fill in Customer details, Order details and 1-n OrderLine details. He hits save and they go to the database, he hits cancel they don't.

So, in this case the model might ask the CustomerRepository for a customer, then the OrderRepository for a new Order, then the OrderLineRepository for each new Line, then tell the Unit of Work to save them.

Does that sound reasonable? It does to me, I think it's where the separation is defined. I'm half tempted to have another API between the model and the repositories. No, that's silly.

EDIT 2: This is an excellent article that has sort of [helped](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/) a little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I designed my unit of work and repository classes similar to how it's described [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx).  The basic idea of the `IUnitOfWork` class is that it handles all the database work itself.

I then added (to my `IUnitOfWork` class and implementations) a `BeginTransaction()` method, which opens a `TransactionScope()` object, and then added a `EndTransaction(bool commit)` method.  This method handles closing the transaction, either by committing the transaction to the database (if true) or rolling back the transaction (if false).

This allows me to do control complicated transactions allowing multiple commits to be rolled back.

**Edit:**
My line of thinking is you want your UnitOfWork object to know about the repositories and not the other way around.  This is my opinion, and you'll find people who like the opposite but here's why.

When you want to deal with the database in some way, you want it all constrained by your current unit of work.  So to me it makes logical sense to go through the unit of work in order to access your repositories, rather than having your repositories access your unit of work.

It also makes it easier if you need to branch out and do multiple things on different databases (for example, if history data is written to a different database than live data, or if you are doing horizontal database partitioning), since each database would have it's own unit of work.  The reason is that if you make repositories know of the unit of work, you need to create one unit of work for each database, plus copy of each repository that you need for each unit of work you may need to access it to.

Finally, keeping access to your repositories as being accessed only through your unit of work keeps the API simple for the developers.  For starters, you only need to instantiate 1 object (the unit of work) instead of 1 unit of work object plus however many repository objects you may need.  It keeps your code simple (imho) and makes things a bit less error prone for the developers.

Comment: That's a good article, I hadn't seen that before. I think I'm still struggling a bit with which classes know of which other classes, i.e. does the repository know about the unit of work, does the unit of work know about all repositories? Actually here's a good question: I'll put it in an edit above if that's ok...

Comment: I added my response in an edit as it was too long for a comment

Comment: Kall, that's almost exactly how I would have done it in the past, and it does make perfect sense to me :) I'll take it as the answer, but if anyone vehemently disagrees please do say :)

Comment: I've done it both ways in the past as well, but once I saw the article I posted I switched to this method, and I have been happy about it since.  As a bonus, it also simplifies any dependency injection as well :)

Comment: Nice, but, how can a repository know which unit-of-work instance he has to use ?  What if you have multiple unit-of-works open at the same time ?  Ah, I see, your unitofwork has properties which access a repository, which is nice ... but, you'll have no generic unitofwork then ...  Although, it is something I'll have to think about when I'll start a new project.  Perhaps I'll create extension methods on my UnitOfWork class then, which are specific for the project ...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  I never access a specific unit of work, I always use my `IUnitOfWork` to access data, wheither I am using my entity framework `EFUnitOfWork` or `InMemoryUnitOfWork`.  The UnitOfWork class creates a repository of the correct type depending on what type of unit of work you are creating.  The `UnitOfWork` classes only map to `IRepositories`, not to strong-typed repositories

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say for sure without more detail, but I'd look into implementing from the `IDbConnection` interface and associated interfaces. It gives you an interface most C# coders with any experience will be familiar with.

Under the hood, to be honest, it really depends on the efficiency if your storage mechanism. If it handles lots of changes efficiently, then you're probably better off having your rollback mechanism build a list of actions that it should take to do a rollback, which is discarded on a 'commit'. If on the other hand updates are expensive, then have you transaction mechanism maintain a list of actions to do on a commit, which are discarded on a rollback. You also need to think about whether or not other code should see updates prior to a commit; with the former approach they will, with the latter, they won't.

Comment: Yeah, I'm hitting a lot of "it depends", and I fully appreciate that. I can see a half dozen ways of doing concrete implementations, and have done so in the past, but it's defining the abstraction that I'm struggling with, specifically doing so under the guiding light of these patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this by using a framework like NHibernate or Entity Framework to do this. :)
NHibernate allows you to use POCO's, and does all the plumbing for you already.

Comment: One of my goals is to have a persistence layer for both NHibernate and EF beyond/behind the unit of work. There are two projects, one is actual real world work, the other is prototype testing rig and it's the rig I'm working on at the moment to get the shape of the code down.